# 0:25:01,819 WARN [HtmlImageRendererBase] ALT attribute is missing for : j_id113

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy a web application from my Eclipse to Jboss 6.x on a localhost. And i keep getting this error.

```
10:25:01,819 WARN  [HtmlImageRendererBase] ALT attribute is missing for : j_id113
10:25:05,823 WARN  [HtmlImageRendererBase] ALT attribute is missing for : j_id81
```

I have other applications deployed in the same jboss application server. I dont see any error related to my application.

I want to know what is wrong with jboss, googling didnt help at all ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that an application using JSF does not set an `alt` attribute on a [graphicImage](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/h/graphicImage.html) tag and that the JSF implementation treats this as a warning.

*`j_id113` looks like an auto-generated ID set on a component when one is not explicitly set.*

Comment: @tsegay - this warning is emitted by a renderer, so it will only happen when one of the pages is emitted to a browser; since the server is on localhost, you should be able to tell by which application you were using at the time; in any case, you should be able to disable the warning using `jboss-log4j.xml`.